# How feasible is using OpenMP specifications with OpenCL/CUDA together?

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, opencl, gpu, openmp

I would like to to divide my work between the CPU and the GPU/APU. Half of the work on the CPU using OpenMP (to leverage the multi-core), and using OpenCL (or CUDA) to accelerate the other half on the GPU or the APU.

I have looked for technical work , but all I found was a comparison between the performance of the two models only.

Comment: Yes, you can do it, and the CUDA samples provide a sample code demonstrating OpenMP and CUDA working together.   Something similar is possible with OpenCL.  You'll find plenty of CUDA + OpenMP examples also simply by searching on both tags here on SO.  I.e. click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuda+openmp)

Comment: To share kernel code you could even use OpenCL for the CPU part using (for example) Intel's OpenCL CPU driver. It will use all the cores, but I don't know how optimized the CPU kernel compiler is compared to what you're using with OpenMP.

Comment: @Dithermaster I meant using the OpenMP to further divide the serial part on the CPU .. not sharing a parallel  kernel .. but I understood your answer ,, it may work for another problem ,  bench-marking will be a must in this case

Answer (score 1):

Not only is it feasible, it is common.

Many of the official CUDA samples use OpenMP. There is even a [CUDA OpenMP example](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cudaopenmp).